# Mold odour immediately after rain! No sign inside or outside

Tags: mold, moisture, smell, rain

I live on Prince Edward Island, on the east side of Canada. We renovated our old building completely last year, so everything is new and neat except the main structure. Now immediately after rain, we smell a bad mold odor that I could not find any reason for. I used a dehumidifier in the basement and while it shows humidity below 50, the smell is still felt just on the main floor.

Our finished basement is dry and fine and the crawl space is encapsulated. I am a bit confused and don't know where to start to find the source.

Comment: So sorry to hear that. Do you have a question?

Comment: Mold usually likes dark humid spaces, so can be hiding somewhere you can't see easy.  Higher humidity after a rain can increase mold activity.  Will need to find it and have it tested.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see how this _Question_ & Answer board is different from regular discussion forums. As it stands, you've given us next to nothing to work from. Even the "detail" of "the east side of Canada" is quite rather broad, I mean, that covers what, 5 provinces, maybe more?

Comment: @FreeMan  Quite sure most Newfies not happy with you.

Comment: @FreeMan >>new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Comment: I hope you find the source.  I suggest you carefully check under sinks, and bathroom floors around a toilet.  After that, you may want to use a dehumidifier to reduce the humidity in the house.

Comment: @crip659 no offense meant to any of my northern neighbors, I made a random guess. Looking at a map today, I'd guess Newfoundland, Quebec, New Brunswick, PEI, and Nova Scotia (which matches the 5 of my guess) would be considered eastern provinces, but again, it was so ill defined (at least to an international audience) that it's not clear. Heck, one _could_ include Ontario and Manitoba in the "east side of Canada" since if one divides the country roughly in half (by eyeball) East/West, they would be on the Eastern (roughly) half.

Comment: It's been 2 days. Has it rained since? Do you still smell it? To find odors, you really have to be there. When you smell it, you have to walk around the house sniffing, like a dog (not necessarily on all fours, but you may have to get down on the ground if the source seems to be low), looking for where the odor is the strongest. Once you've identified the strongest odor, you've likely found the source, then you have to figure out what's there that smells.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your kind consideration.  tried few times to find the source (s) of the issue. There are two sections of more odors. One is the crawlspace that is not too much but I want to redo the encapsulation. The second is a different bad smell in the stairs and I couldn't yet find any reason. I started to clean all around the foundation to pour soil and create a sloping surface to take the water away. I may use a layer of moisture barrier and gravel on top of that. I keep trying.